# Virtual video capture device?

Tags: macos, video, video-editing

Is it possible to create a virtual video capture device in Mac OS?

Sort of like how [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/) creates virtual audio devices...?

I'd like to have a setup where I can take the input from say my laptop's HD camera, processed it with opencv, and then pipe that to some other program that is pretending to be a video capture device (ie it would present itself on video input selection dialogs).

Is it possible to create such a virtual video device, similarly to how audio ones are made?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Apple hardware, software or services in the [scope defined](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Kindly consider [editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/355125/edit) the question and specify how is it relevant to Apple hardware or software or that you are seeking a solution on Apple platform.

Comment: Of course this is on topic, and very much about Mac software....

Answer (score 1):

You can create such a virtual camera device by using the Webcamoid software:

https://webcamoid.github.io/

It supports the virtual camera feature in version 8.5.0 and later.